# Is managed code is the only way to use SMO in c++?

Tags: .net, c++, sql-server, managed-code

I have to work with SQLSERVER SMO in C++. Is Managed code is the only way to work with SQLSERVER SMO in C++ ?

I have tried many ways.. but I found that using managed code is the only option. Are there other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can [expose .NET assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx) to standard COM infrastructure, but that requires changes to the source code (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4w8x20h.aspx)). You may try and create a COM-aware wrappers around standard SMO objects and then use them as regular COM classes in C++.

Comment: here the solution is dependentg on tlb files.