# Is there any way to use SMO in c++ other than Managed Code?

Tags: c++, sql-server

Is there any way to use SQLSERVER SMO(sqlserver management Objects) in c++ other than Managed Code?

Help me in this regard...

I sincerely request dont give the comment as duplicate still i am not getting Clear answer

Comment: Can you expand the SMO acronym?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out. This question has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771203/is-managed-code-is-the-only-way-to-use-smo-in-c) without a satisfactory answer.

SMO is strictly manage code. The previous version, DMO, could be used in unmanaged code. If you need to use SMO, you have to use either C++/CLI or create wrappers for COM.

From the [MSDN Documentation on SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx):

> The SMO object model supersedes and
>   replaces SQL-DMO. SMO supports SQL
>   Server 2000, SQL Server 2005, and SQL
>   Server 2008. It supports more SQL
>   Server management tasks and contains
>   many new features in SQL Server. SMO
>   is designed to be more efficient and
>   provide more control.
>
> The DMO library is a COM object model,
>   whereas SMO is implemented as a .NET
>   Framework assembly. COM components are
>   libraries that provide re-usable
>   functionality to applications and in
>   unmanaged application programming. The
>   .NET Framework assemblies provide
>   reusable functionality for the .NET
>   Framework to write managed code
>   applications.
>
> During the transition to .NET
>   Framework technology it is possible to
>   have applications written partly in
>   managed code and partly in unmanaged
>   code. The .NET Framework lets you
>   interface with COM components, which
>   requires a Primary Interop Assembly. A
>   runtime wrapper is required for
>   SQL-DMO so that it can be called from
>   a .NET Framework -based application.

Comment: Thanks jose Basilio for ur support.mow i am satisfied with ur support